# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache-2

I am using the spring 3.2 version along with `net.sf` cache, but while doing mvn build I am  getting `NoClassDefFoundError` for `EhCacheFactoryBean`, but I checked a similar class available in my classpath
below is my stack trace

```
      Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
distributorStartupAndConfigurationListener': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field: protected DistributorConfiguration 
DistributorStartupAndConfigurationListener.distributorConfiguration;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filePathCache' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/cms-client-context.xml]:Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean Caused by:   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected DistributorConfiguration .DistributorStartupAndConfigurationListener.distributorConfiguration;  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
         creating 
                 bean with name 'filePathCache' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/cms-client- 
                 context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
                 org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean Caused by: 
                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
                 'filePathCache' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/cms-client-context.xml]: 
                 Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
                initialize class org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean Caused by: 
           **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
     org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean**
```

below is my `pom.xml`

> ```
>     <dependency> 
>      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
>      <version>5.3.21</version>
>     </dependency> 
>
>     <dependency> 
>       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
>       <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
>       <version>2.10.9.2</version> 
>     </dependency>
>    
>     <repository> 
>      <id>sourceforge</id>
>      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/sourceforge/</url> 
>       <releases> 
>         <enabled>true</enabled>
>       </releases>
>      <snapshots>
>      <enabled>true</enabled>
>      </snapshots> 
>     </repository>
>     
>      And in application-context.xml : 
>     
>     <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"> 
>     <property name="cacheManagerRef"> 
>       <ref local="ehcache"/> 
>     </property> 
>     </bean>
>     
>     <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
>      <property name="configLocation"> 
>        <value>classpath:META-INF/spring/ehcache.xml</value> 
>       </property> 
>     </bean>
>     
>     <bean id="filePathCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean"> 
>     <property name="cacheManager"> <ref local="cacheManager" /> </property> 
>     <property name="cacheName"> <value>getFilePathCache</value> </property> 
>     </bean>
> ```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, Could you please help me resolve this issue?